# Detection of tapped meta

Tags: key-bindings

Is it possible for emacs to detect a press and immediate release of a meta key?
I would consider binding this to `toggle-input-method`.  I know there are external programs that can make tapping a modifier equivalent to a different key, but I would like to keep the ability to bring up a menu by tapping `alt`/`meta`.

Comment: I suspect that would have to be done at the level of the window manager or desktop environment, rather than from within Emacs. I don't think the meta modifier keypress is passed on to Emacs until another keypress is added.

Comment: As an alternative, why not just tap `ESC` (Escape key)? It should have the effect it seems you are looking for.

Comment: @Drew can you bind `ESC` on its own? Once a key is defined as a prefix key, is there a way to respond to a single press?

Comment: @Tyler `(global-set-key [escape] (lambda () (interactive) (message "Hi!")))`

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen sure, that works, but it breaks any other use of the `ESC` key as a prefix (if you use them)... Although I never do personally, so I may have to use this myself - cool.

Comment: Whether it's `ESC` or what was requested (Meta), it seems like the OP *wants* a single press of the key to do `toggle-input-method`. Unless you make another char the `meta-prefix-char` that will, yes, wipe out meta prefixes. Anyway, it's not very clear what the OP wants, and if it is to use the `Meta` (e.g. `Alt`) key the way he says then I don't know of a reasonable answer.